# One method (ActionResult) for all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a method which will work for all pages including layout page? I get GET parameter and The GET parameter is on every page, therefore I think - this solution is really bad.

```
 [HttpGet]     
    public ActionResult Default(string par)
    { ... }

 [HttpGet]     
    public ActionResult SecondPage(string par)
    { ... }
```

I want something like this:

```
 [HttpGet]     
    public ActionResult Layout/allPages (string lang)
    { ... }
```

Comment: Can't you have a base class for a generic route which can be used for all pages?

Comment: Everything can be, but I dunno how to do it - that's why I asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, you just need to use "routing" correctly. 
For example, suppose you have an Action that manage all pages changing template associated to the master page, you can write this method:

```
public ActionResult Serve(string pageName, string par) 
{
    // Do your logic with par
    return View(pageName);
}
```

In your global.asax you can map a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ServePage",
    url: "Pages/{pageName}.aspx",
    defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Serve" });
```